# Rails 5: How can I render a view in a controller without the URL changing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following route:

```
Shop::Engine.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#index'
  get 'jobs/apply'=>'applicants#new'
  resources :applicants, only: [:create]
end
```

This works as expected. The url renders the expected view.

The page contains a form. When the user submits it successfully, I want to replace the form with a success message. With that in mind, I have created a new template:

```
# success.html.erb
<h1>Thank you</h1>
<p>Your application has been submitted.</p>
```

My create action looks like this:

```
def create
  @applicant = Applicant.new(safe_params)

  if @applicant.save
    render 'success'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

It works as expected, except that the URL in the address bar changes to: `http://localhost:3000/applicants`. I want it to remain: `http://localhost:3000/jobs/apply`.

How do I render the success message view without the url changing? Am I even going about the right way? Is there another way of rendering success messages without redirecting to another route?

Comment: Use javascript with a remote form. That ought to do the trick. There are a ton of articles, blogs, tuts, etc. to get you on your way.

Comment: You have to send your form as `remote: true` which will trigger the form target action asynchronously (Ajax). Then you can render a `js.erb` view that has code to manipulate the Dom (removing form div and replacing it with a message)